# angularjs controller test failed

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

I am struggle up to write a simple angularjs controller testcase by angular-mock and jasmine.

I am using angularjs v1.0.8 and jasmine 1.3.0.

My code is like this:

**1. demoController.js**

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

 $scope.data = 'hello';

});
```

**2. controllerTest.js**

```
'use strict';

describe('MainCtrl', function () {

var scope = null;

beforeEach(angular.module('MyApp'));

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller){

 scope = $rootScope.$new();

 $controller('MainCtrl', {$scope: scope});

}));

it('should have variable text = "Hello World!"', function(){

 expect(scope.data).toBe('hello');

});

});
```

As you can find from my SpecRunner.htm file I have the following files in path.

angular-1.0.8.min.js

angular-mocks.js

angular-scenario.js

angular-resource.js

jasmine.js

jasmine-html.js

demoControllers.js

controllerTest.js"

Now it I execute the html file, I am receiving the following error.

```
**TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply'**

**ReferenceError: inject is not defined**
    at null.<anonymous>
```

So my question is, am I doing anything wrong or missed any configuration?

Comment: I got that a while ago and using `angular.mock.inject(/* ... */)` instead of `inject(/* ... */)` fixed it for me.  If that doesn't fix it, see if you can get a plunkr and I'll take a look.  If it does, let me know and I'll post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
beforeEach(module('MyApp'));

describe('MainCtrl', function () {

var scope = null;

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller){

 scope = $rootScope.$new();

 $controller('MainCtrl', {$scope: scope});

}));

it('should have variable text = "Hello World!"', function(){

 expect(scope.data).toBe('hello');

});

});
```